# BSD expr difference with GNU expr

Tags: bash, macos, gnu, bsd, expr

Does any one know why

```
expr "4" : '-\?[0-9]\+$'
```

returns 0 on Mac OS X and 1 on Linux?

Fact: Mac uses BSD expr
Linux uses GNU

Sorry, I originally typed

```
expr "4" : '-\?[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: It outputs 0 in Linux as well.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo.

Comment: Looking forward to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expr` takes a basic regular expression, not an extended regular expression. (See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html for the definition of each.)

Basic regular expressions do not support the either the `?` and `+` operators; you need to use bounds instead.

- `?` is implemented with `\{0,1\}` (0 to 1 occurrences)
- `+` is implemented with `\{1,\}` (1 or more occurrences)

GNU `expr` appears to allow them as an extension if they are escaped.

The following is a portable call that should work in any POSIX-compliant implementation of `expr`:

```
expr "4" : '-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}$'
```